# How to track ERC20 token creations on Ethereum blockhain with web3.js using Infura API?

Tags: web3js, tokens, javascript, infura, api

I'm trying to fetch new ERC20 tokens from the blockchain transactions, my code is scanning the blocks and when I tried to log transactions it works well, (dumping bunch of logs). However I don't know how to catch the ERC20 token creation and then send it to my telegram and log it to the console and push it to my JSON. Not sure what am I missing.

Code:

```
//Web3 
const infura = process.env.Infura;
const Web3 = require('web3').default;
const web3 = new Web3(`wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/${infura}`);

// Main Funcion setup
let lastBlockNumber = LastBlock; //Get LastBlockNumber from the .JSON file

async function checkNewBlocks() {
  try {
    const currentBlockNumber = BigInt(await web3.eth.getBlockNumber());

    if (currentBlockNumber > lastBlockNumber) {
      for (let i = lastBlockNumber + BigInt(1); i <= currentBlockNumber; i = i + BigInt(1)) {
        try {
          const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(Number(i), true);
          console.log('Checking block:', i.toString());
          if (block && block.transactions) {
            for (const transaction of block.transactions) {
              if (transaction.to === null && transaction.creates !== undefined) {
                bot.sendMessage(myself, `I found ${transaction.creates}`, {parse_mode: 'HTML'});
                console.log('New contract:', transaction.creates);

                const contract = new web3.eth.Contract([
                    { name: 'name', type: 'function', constant: true, outputs: [{ type: 'string' }] }, 
                    { name: 'symbol', type: 'function', constant: true, outputs: [{ type: 'string' }] },
                    { name: 'totalSupply', type: 'function', constant: true, outputs: [{ type: 'uint256' }]},
                  ], transaction.creates);
                  
                  try {
                    const name = await contract.methods.name().call();
                    const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
                    const totalSupply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
                    if (name && symbol && totalSupply) {
                        let newContract = {
                        "contractAddress": transaction.creates,
                        "ticker": symbol
                    };      
                    // Add the new contract to the array
                    foundContracts.foundcontracts.push(newContract);      
                    // Write the updated JSON back to the file
                    fs.writeFileSync(contracts, JSON.stringify(foundContracts));        
                    //send me a message on telegram
                    bot.sendMessage(myself, `New ERC20 contract! \n\nContract: <a href='https://etherscan.io/address/${transaction.creates}'>${transaction.creates}</a>  \nName: ${name} \nSymbol: ${symbol}`, {parse_mode: 'HTML'});
                    console.log('Token name:', name, 'symbol:', symbol, 'Total supply:', totalSupply);
                    }
                  } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Failed to get token name/symbol/totalSupply:', error);
                  }
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.log('Failed to fetch block:', i.toString());
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('Failed to fetch block:', i.toString(), 'Error:', error);
        }
      }
      lastBlockNumber = currentBlockNumber;
      getBlockNumber.latestblock = currentBlockNumber.toString();
      try {
        // Convert it back to JSON and write it to the file
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(getBlockNumber), 'utf8');
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Failed to write to file:', error);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to get block number:', error);
  }
}

// Check for new blocks every 5 seconds
setInterval(checkNewBlocks, 5000);
```

I have been running the code for several hours on my server, unfortunately all logs are just fetches of the blocks.

Logs:

```
Checking block: 17791260
Checking block: 17791261
Checking block: 17791262
Checking block: 17791263
Checking block: 17791264
Checking block: 17791265
Checking block: 17791266
Checking block: 17791267
Checking block: 17791268
Checking block: 17791269
.......
```

No error logs so far, I have found out on Bitquery newly created ERC20 tokens (several of them), my bot didn't catch a single one unfortunately.

Any ideas or it's not possible to make this happen with Infura?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Because if you are interested in finding new ERC20 coins that starts trading, you can watch the liquidity pool creation events instead. It makes the whole process much easier and is usually what people are after anyway. Because that's when you can actually buy the token. 

Let me know and I can show you how to do that.

Comment: Hi, my goal was to find new erc20 tokens before the trading starts, but I sorted that out! :-)

Comment: @Filip Anyway, that would be also interesting for me to do. Does the pool creation track all the dexes for example in the base chain also?